# How do I taper a cylindrical object in blender?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, transforms, constraints, topology

I'm trying to taper the object (on the bottom of the picture) in blender from it's cylindrical shape to match the profile of the tapered one (top of the picture). [image: help needed]

[image]

Comment: lattice modifier

Comment: Use Simple Deform modifier and set it to Taper option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shift a Add lattice

Scale the lattice so the model covers completely

Select the lattice and in the properties panel add some division to it

Select the mesh or cylinder and add lattice modifier

In the object select lattice

Now click the Lattice and tab to edit mode select the vert and scale up and down to get the shape

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That should be easy. Add a *lattice* to your scene. A basic one with just 8 vertices is best. Scale it in **world space** to match your engraved form. Don't do it in edit mode! Now, when the lattice object enwraps your engraved form completely, add a *lattice modifier* to it. Now, if you move a vertex of your lattice in **edit mode**, the mesh deforms accordingly.

Select the top four vertices of the lattice, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and click *Cursor To Selected*. Now, you can simply scale these vertices, until your engraved form match the form of your cylinder.