# Remove Taper from object

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view

Somehow in my adventures of creating this thread, I tapered the whole object. Is there a way to straighten it out again? I can't find any solutions to this issue.

I am sure re-designing it would be faster, but I want to learn.

[image: 2D View]

Comment: You can use proprtional editing or a lattice modifier. Here's a related (if not duplicate) question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92063/how-do-i-taper-a-cylindrical-object-in-blender.

Comment: @Carlo looks like the OP is looking for the opposite, to "straighten it out again", still this kind of can be done with Simple Deform > Taper (only tapering in the opposite way).

Comment: @MrZak I linked the question because it contained some possible solutions, despite the problem is (apparently) the opposite. BTW using simple deform modifier is probably the best solution for this task: quick to set up and non-distructive

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach showing how you can achieve it using the ***Cast Modifier (Cylinder)*** and *shrink/flatten* tool. 
[image]

Add the *Cast Modifier* and set its mode to *Cylinder*. Set *Factor* and *Radius* values to *1.000*. Apply modifier. Next enter the *Edit Mode*, select all the inner faces with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to scale them down. Finally in *Object Mode* press <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to scale the whole object fitting the original mesh's parameters.
[image]

Comment: I tried this method. It made a difference for sure (once i figured out where my origin point needed to be) but I still have a slight taper. 11.5mm at the bottom and 10.75mm at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Using both methods, starting with the cast modifier followed by simple deform I was able to achieve my desired results. The cast modifier did 90% of the work, then I achieved the rest with the simple deform taper. I am now within .05mm between the top and bottom now.

Thank you all!!!!